# Set parameters in Package Manager Console

Tags: nuget-package, package-managers

in extension I have a code:

```
function Enable-RazorGenerator {
    param(
        [parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        [string]$ProjectName
    )
```

So How Can I set this parameter: $ProjectName in Package Manager Console?